# Mercurial(hg) copying part of repository into another rpository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have two repositories:
Repository `A` is empty.

Repository `B` with:

```
module1
module2
module3
```

How i can copy `module1` from repository `B` into repository `A` with all relevant commit history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Convert](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) `/module1` into independent repo
- Force pull (because they are unrelated) module1-repo to A